# Ambari cluster + Service Auto Start Configuration by API

Tags: json, linux, hadoop, ambari

[image]Ambari services can be configured to start automatically on system boot. Each service can be configured to start all components, masters and workers, or selectively.

so how to enable all services in ambari cluster to start automatically on system boot by API ?

Remark - by default all services are disabled

Comment: Your first sentence makes it sound like you already know it can be done, so why the question?

Comment: I can do that from ambari GUI , but I want to do it by API , as part of automation process , I will happy to get answer about API

Comment: Every action in the Ambari GUI is an API request. Open Chrome/Firefox dev tools window and watch the network requests as you perform actions. Ambari cannot start a remote server's services when it boots, AFAIK

Comment: this is the configuration from the ambari cluster , and configuration can be change by ambari API request

Comment: from ambari GUI go to --> admin --> service auto start , and then you can see alll services that are disabled , as I said I want to change all them to be enabled from API command that runs from linux machines

Comment: A curl request can be done on any machine. Not just Linux. And that option isn't on the Ambari I have.

Comment: Anyways, search here for  "Set auto-start flags of a cluster" https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Recovery%3A+auto+start+components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153627/discussion-between-king-david-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use auto-restart API, refer following document  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Recovery%3A+auto+start+components

**Syntax.** Following is syntax of API

```
curl -u admin:<password> -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X PUT 'http://<ambari host>:<ambari port>/api/v1/clusters/<cluster_name>/components?ServiceComponentInfo/component_name.in(<component name>)' -d '{"ServiceComponentInfo" : {"recovery_enabled":"true"}}'
```

**Example**. To set auto-restart for `app timeline server` component of `YARN` service use `curl` command as follows.

```
curl -u admin:<password> -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDPCL/components?ServiceComponentInfo/component_name.in(APP_TIMELINE_SERVER)' -d '{"ServiceComponentInfo" : {"recovery_enabled":"true"}}'
```

**NOTE**: You can find list of components from `http://<ambarihost>:<ambari port>/api/v1/clusters/Fenton/components`

Comment: curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP01/components?ServiceComponentInfo/component_name.in(Schema_Registry)' -d '{"YARN" : {"recovery_enabled":"true"}}'

Comment: I run this syntax , but something is wrong can you help me?

Comment: @King David, I have added example in answer. Please use curl command accordingly. If it still fails add your command and error in comment.

Comment: its work , but strange see my update the picture , why its still disable ad defined in the pic ?